# How do I disable the mouse back/forward buttons?

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse, mouse-buttons

I have a Logitech MX Anywhere 2. Whatever I try it seems impossible to disable the "back/forwards" side buttons on it. I've gone into the Logitech software for it and made sure they are set to "None" on both, but they still are hot. I've even tried installing an extension to my browser called BackStop and not even that has been able to disable these devil spawns. Everything as far as I can see is set to not use these buttons, but they are still doing their thing regardless of the settings. Which is more then mildly annoying to me as I'm left handed, and I don't have count of how often I've been in the middle of something and suddenly the browser jumps back so I lose everything.

Comment: Thank you Randy Schuman! That actually did the trick. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Using a form history control plugin might do a good idea even if that problem is now solved. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "X-Mouse Button Control" utility will allow you to selectively disable buttons on your mouse.

**Requirements:**

"A mouse and driver that supports 5 buttons. 
NOTE: If your mouse has 5 buttons but the 4th and 5th buttons don't do anything in by default - then XMBC may not be for you. This software relies on the driver to send the default 4th and 5th mouse button messages which usually default to BACK/NEXT in browsers and other programs. Having said that you can still remap the standard 2 buttons and scroll wheel.
A compatible version of Microsoft Windows. 
X-Mouse Button Control supports all 32bit (x86) and 64bit (x64) editions of Windows from Windows XP to 10, including Windows Server editions!"

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm